# Dataframe reindex on a column

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe

```
      ticker        date   dateValue
549      RCG  2015-01-02    10
692      RCG  2015-01-05    8
```

I want to have this have reindex

```
foo =  foo.reindex(index=['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02'])

ticker        date   dateValue
RCG  2015-01-01    N/A
RCG  2015-01-02    10
```

Instead I get

```
       ticker date   dateValue
2015-01-01    NaN  NaN          NaN
2015-01-02    NaN  NaN          NaN
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply set the index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ticker': ['RCG','RCG'], 'date': ['2015-01-02','2015-01-05'], 'dateValue':[10,8]}, index=[549, 692])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
print(df)

            dateValue ticker
date                        
2015-01-02         10    RCG
2015-01-05          8    RCG
```

Is it the expected result ?

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the set_index

Comment: i also had the same problem while using `reindex `,why did `reindex` return columns with Nan values ?

Comment: See the docs on [`pandas.DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html). They have totally different applications. Reindex is more similar to `.loc` but allowing indices that were not previously present.